# Is it mandatory to create a variable associated with a property in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties

In general, I do my interfaces like this:

```
@interface Gui2UtilityCell : NSObject{
    NSString* myString;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* mystring;

@end
```

In this case, the `NSString* myString;` is it Mandatory ? If yes, what the difference between the previous code and this one:

```
@interface Gui2UtilityCell : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* mystring;

@end
```

Comment: This has been asked so many times. Please check before asking.

Comment: Guys do not downvote such questions because:
1. It is simplier to ask then to find.
2. It allows noobs like me to answer and raise reputation.
Though, Anthony you should of course use a search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I still need to declare the instance variable if I am using @property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459987/do-i-still-need-to-declare-the-instance-variable-if-i-am-using-property)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903651/is-there-any-reason-to-declare-ivars-if-youre-using-properties-exclusively-in-o http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159725/difference-between-interface-declaration-and-property-declaration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572114/why-declare-object-in-interface-when-used-property-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't create a variable by yourself it will be created automatically. You may create the variable for your property with the name: yourPropertyName_ (in your case it will be myString_) to differentiate the instance variable and the name of property.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, there is no difference.

There is a good answer here:
[Do declared properties require a corresponding instance variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074248/properties-and-instance-variables-in-objective-c-2-0)